# Apple Policy - about loading Java script from Server - Cordova App

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

We have developed Cordova Hybrid App using Ionic framework and will deliver this app through Apple and google's store.

I have read Apple Policy document that insist "We Should not dynamically update App without through Apple store".

I would like to load two JS files from my server. It will never change App purpose and look and feel.

I am bit more confused about Apple policy document . Any assistance in this topics are much more appreciated.

Thanks
Nagarajan S

Comment: if the JS contains code that you can run then it is not compliant with the policy, if the JS was just some JSON or something (data) then it's (probably) fine

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only Apple can answer this question when you ask them about your specific scenario.

Comment: Yes Gentle man... thanks... It would be correct to ask them... thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a try. The worst thing that could happen is that you wait for a week, get rejected and have to adapt your app and resubmit it...

I never had a problem with external JS files from CDNs, but that doesn't have to mean anything for your case.

That said, why not simply include the files in your app? Why should Apple trust you not changing the app?